# Remove leading and trailing zeros from multidimensional list in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list such as:

```
my_list = [[1,2,2,1], [0,0,1,2], [1,2,0,0], [1,0,0,1]]
```

I need to remove only the leading and trailing zeros from the inner lists, so that I end up with:

```
new_list = [[1,2,2,1], [1,2], [1,2], [1,0,0,1]]
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: That's great, but what have you tried?

Comment: I tried iterating through the list and using len() to determine the length of each sublist then looking for zeros at the beginning and end, but this doesn't help when there are multiple zeros leading or trailing.

Comment: Downvote? What is the problem? I really didn't want to show what I had tried as I was getting quite lost, and it would not have added to the explanation.

Comment: Without code, this is a "write my code for me" question. With code, it is a "help me fix my code" question. That's why you're getting downvoted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for sub_list in my_list:
    for dx in (0, -1):
        while sub_list and sub_list[dx] == 0:
            sub_list.pop(dx)
```

Comment: This works, without the need for numpy.

Comment: That will give an IndexError if operating on an empty list. If it's possible to have a list that contains nothing but 0s, check for the list being non-empty in the while test.

Comment: Good point. I will take this into account when validating the list input.

Comment: @BrendenBrown:  Good point.  I modified the answer to handle empty lists and zero-only lists.

Comment: Very keen solution. The list and sublists are transformed in place.

Answer (score 8):

```
my_list = [[1,2,2,1], [0,0,1,2], [1,2,0,0], [1,0,0,1]]
my_list =[np.trim_zeros(np.array(a)) for a in my_list]
>>> my_list
[array([1, 2, 2, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 0, 0, 1])]
```

If you want numpy.

Can also just do:

```
>>> my_list =[np.trim_zeros(a) for a in my_list]
>>> my_list
[[1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Some timings:

```
Numpy
>>> timeit.timeit('my_list =[np.trim_zeros(a) for a in my_list]',setup='import numpy as np; my_list = [[1,2,2,1], [0,0,1,2], [1,2,0,0], [1,0,0,1]]', number=10000)
0.08429217338562012

Numpy w/convert array
>>> timeit.timeit('my_list =[np.trim_zeros(np.array(a)) for a in my_list]',setup='import numpy as np; my_list = [[1,2,2,1], [0,0,1,2], [1,2,0,0], [1,0,0,1]]', number=10000)
0.6929900646209717
```

So really best off not to convert at np.array unless you are going to use that type later.

Comment: much better than my string hackery below :)

Answer (score 4):

```
new_list = [map(int,"".join(map(str,x)).strip("0")) for x in my_list]
```

might work

```
>>> new_list = [map(int,"".join(map(str,x)).strip("0")) for x in my_list]
>>> new_list
[[1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: what if the last element is 10, your code will strip it's `0` too.

Comment: Actually in this case, that is ok. My integers are limited to <= 3.

Answer (score 2):

Using a single list comprehension, with slicing by filtered generator comprehension:

```
new_list = [l[next((i for i, n in enumerate(l) if n != 0), 0):
              next((len(l) - i for i, n in enumerate(reversed(l)) if n != 0), 0)]
            for l in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `regex` and `itertools.chain()`:

```
In [91]: my_lis=[[1,2,2,1], [0,0,1,2], [1,2,0,0], [1,0,0,10]]

In [92]: my_lis1=[[y.split() for y in filter(None,re.split(r"\b\s?0\s?\b",
                                     " ".join(map(str,x))))] for x in my_lis]

In [93]: [map(int,chain(*x)) for x in my_lis1]
Out[93]: [[1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 10]]
```