# Python split list at zeros

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove leading and trailing zeros from multidimensional list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633901/remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-from-multidimensional-list-in-python)

if I have a list such as:

```
my_list = [[1,2,0,1], [1,0,0,1]]
```

I want to split this at the zeros and throw them away, so that I end up with something like:

```
my_list = [[[1, 2], [1]], [[1],[1]]]
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted so heavily...

Comment: this is your 3rd question in a row, and in each of those you didn't seem to have tried anything yourself.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: This is very straight forward, if you looked at the answer to one of your other questions that uses `itertools.groupby()`.

Comment: I apologize. But the answers to the larger problem were not sufficient to get the answer needed. If you reference my first question I still need to deal with leading zeros. So I tried to break my problem apart and get a answers I could use to build a solution to the larger problem myself.

Comment: I would be quite happy to describe that problem in more detail but my attempts to do so have resulted in more confusion. Maybe stackoverflow is not the place for this type of open-ended problem.

Comment: Correct. Stackoverflow questions should be specific. However sometimes quite open ended questions are tolerated.

Comment: Yes. I do try to be specific and show my attempts. Unfortunately, the problem today was one where I had little idea of the direction to take. I was hoping to get some guidance on this type of dealings with lists, and I also saw it as an interesting challenge to those more adept than myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide an conquer, you can use a list comprehension to transform it to a simpler problem

```
def split_a_list_at_zeros(L):
    ...
    return the_split_list

my_list = [split_a_list_at_zeros(item) for item in my_list]
```

and Akavall gives a great hint to split the list

```
from itertools import groupby
def split_a_list_at_zeros(L):
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, key=lambda x:x!=0) if k]
```

Answer (score -1):

Having the nested list as input is a little overly specific, but this function will split a list of numbers based on another number, using the exact same style as string.split()

```
def nsplit(number_list,key):
    s=''.join(map(chr,number_list))
    return [map(ord,x) for x in s.split(chr(key))]

print nsplit([1,2,0,1],0)

[[1,2],[1]]
```