# Split list into several lists at specific values

Tags: python-3.x, list, split

I have a list of elements which internally is separated by 0s.
The format is like that:

```
[0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]
```

I would like to use the zeros as separators and split it into sublists. In that example its:

```
[[], [2, 2], [1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3], [7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]]
```

The zeros will therefore disappear.
A leading zero or an ending zero should make an empty list at the beginning or the end.

Until know, I do that in an ugly way by joining the list together to a string, then split it and make a list of it again.

Is there a fancy pythonic way to do that easier?

Comment: I believe that you can solve your problem using this solution: [Python split list at zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634396/python-split-list-at-zeros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a groupby approach:

```
from itertools import groupby
k = [0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]

gr = groupby(k, lambda a: a==0)

l = [[] if a else [*b] for a,b in gr]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[], [2, 2], [], [1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3], [], [7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]]
```

You can fix the internal [] by:

```
l = [ a for idx,a in enumerate(l) if idx in (0,len(l)) or a]
```

to get

```
[[], [2, 2], [1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3], [7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]]
```

---

You can substitute the list comp by

```
l = []
for a,b in gr:
    if a: 
        l.append([])
    else: 
        l.append([*b])
```

Comment: You would need to filter out the [] to match requirement.

Comment: @AllanWind fixed - but only as addon, thx for the heads-up

Comment: That a wonderful working answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem using this solution: [Python split list at zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634396/python-split-list-at-zeros)

```py
from itertools import groupby

def split_a_list_at_zeros(L):
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(L, key=lambda x:x!=0) if k]

list1 = [0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]

new_list = split_a_list_at_zeros(list1)

print(new_list) # [[2, 2], [1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3], [7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: the first empty list is missing from your output

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
def func(arr):
    indices = [-1] + [i for i in range(len(arr)) if arr[i] == 0] + [len(arr)]
    return [arr[indices[i] + 1 : indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty intuitive solution, but it modifies the list after each pass. Uses the indices, indexing and external list to actually split it.

```
inp = [0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]

out = []
split_on = 0

while inp:
    # accounts for the last split
    if split_on not in inp:
        out.append(inp)
        break

    end_index = inp.index(split_on)
    out.append(inp[:end_index])

    inp = inp[end_index+1:]

print(out)

# [[], [2, 2], [1, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3], [7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6]]
```